# Why does entity object will be detached, after a method returns it? (Spring data JPA)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

Solved: The problem was with an around aspect that modified the return value in the proxy somehow. Sorry for the unanswerable question. Maybe someone learn my fault. And thanks for the helpful answers!

I have a problem with my spring boot console application. I'm using also spring data jpa to persist. Everythings works fine, i can save and find entitys, but when a service class method return an entity it will be detached. When i want to use returned object the application fail becouse object value is null.

It's just an example of the point.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateAttributeConverter.class)
    private LocalDate birth;

    public Person() {
    }
    //getter, setter..
}
```

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    public Person findByName(String name);

}
```

```
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Person findPersonByName(String name) {
        return personRepository.findByName(name); // System.out.println(person.name) -> someone
    }
}
```

```
public class App {

    private Service service;

    public void doSomething(){
        Person person = service.findPersonByName("someone"); 
        // System.out.println(person.name) -> nullpointerEx
    }
}
```

```
//The player like person in the exaple. I must cover some detail in the package names. 
//This is the real exception. As a say above, the code it's just a raw example. Probably don't match for this.
Hibernate: select player0_.id as id1_7_, player0_1_.email as email2_7_, player0_1_.password as password3_7_, player0_.balance as balance1_4_, player0_.birth as birth2_4_, player0_.currency as currency3_4_, player0_.name as name4_4_ from player player0_ inner join user player0_1_ on player0_.id=player0_1_.id where player0_.name=?

14:24:02.087 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
14:24:02.103 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com....Application.main(..Application.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.....view.ConsoleView.printWelcomeMassege(ConsoleView.java:101)
    at com.....App.createPersone(App.java:46)
    at com.....App.play(App.java:33)
    at com....Application.lambda$0(..Application.java:22)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
14:24:02.118 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
14:24:02.118 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
14:24:02.165 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

How can i handle this?

Comment: In the PersonRepository interface, you need to add a class-level annotation Repository.

Comment: Are your entities really persisted in the database? Did you check?

Comment: @Seb Yes i do. I can save in the db.

Comment: @M.Ismail Same issue :/

Comment: @bubisbuble, could you please edit your post by adding the exception details?

Comment: What is the `App` class in your example, is it a controller? How do you invoke the `doSomething` method?

Comment: Do you know what it means when an entity is detached? You're getting an `NPE`, don't mix that up with an entity being detached.

Comment: @AlexandruSomai Yes its a controller but no. Its not a controller like in spring mvc. It has a play method that is called in main method in springboot class. doSomething it's like create person, savePerson, findPersone print "Wellcome" + person.name.

Comment: @bubisbuble I think that's the issues. Because calling it from the main method, you are not in the Spring context. I assume you instantiate the App class with `new App();`? That should be avoided. Just create a Spring MVC controller, call that endpoint, and invoke your `doSomething()` function.

Comment: @AlexandruSomai It is not in the main method. I have a spring boot app class where is in the main and i defined the command line runner. The spring mvc will be the next thing what i'm gonna learn, but now i cannot use it because the task

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `@Column(name = "name")` Annotation

Comment: That is unnecessary, a default convention is applied to derive that when not explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does entity object will be detached, after a method returns it?

Because Service is not declared transactional.

Try:

```
@Service
**@Transactional**
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Person findPersonByName(String name) {
        return personRepository.findByName(name); // System.out.println(person.name) -> someone
    }
}
```

or

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    **@Transactional**
    public Person findPersonByName(String name) {
        return personRepository.findByName(name); // System.out.println(person.name) -> someone
    }
}
```

To reduce the number of annotations and reduce the risk of forgetting one you can also use the custom annotation [TransactionalService](https://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/1.0/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/spring/transaction/stereotype/TransactionalService.html):

```
**@TransactionalService**
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Person findPersonByName(String name) {
        return personRepository.findByName(name); // System.out.println(person.name) -> someone
    }
}
```

TransactionalService is also configured to rollback for [BusinessException](https://www.softsmithy.org/softsmithy-lib/lib/2.1.1/docs/site/apidocs/org/softsmithy/lib/util/BusinessException.html) and its subclasses.

The library, [Drombler Commons](https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-commons), is OpenSource and available from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>drombler-commons-spring-transaction</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Note however that detaching entities does not make them null.
Do you really get the NullPointerException when accessing the name property? This would indicate that the entity could not be found.

But from your code sample it looks that you get the NullPointerException from accessing the uninitialized service.

You need to autowire the Service in the App class to get rid of the NullPointerException:

```
**// Some spring annotation**
public class App {

    **@Autowired**
    private Service service;

    public void doSomething(){
        Person person = service.findPersonByName("someone"); 
        // System.out.println(person.name) -> nullpointerEx
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried the transactional and service annotations but it has no effect. I handle the service bean in appconfig and i set that in the app.

Comment: Sorry i tried but it's not working. I have some aspect that is log every service method call and the service is works fine. When i write into the service method a SystemOut (Person) is valid it has any attribute that i want but when i returned this  some other class its gone, person is null.